# fail2ban на php

Tags: php

Народ посоветуйте плиз готовый модуль или решение на php для бана тех юзеров, которые вводят много раз пароль и не могут набрать его верно. Нужен именно блокировщик, который будет, скажем, после 3 попыток блочить повторную отправку данных на 5 минут. Короче полный аналог fail2ban для линукса

Видел  где-то уже готовые примеры раньше, но сейчас чет уже не могу найти. Самому писать не охота, да возможно уже есть такого плана готовые решения у кого-то на гитхабе. И еще момент, уточняю что капча мне не нужна, нужен именно блокировщик.

Это модуль я хочу использовать для формы авторизации.

Спасибо.

Comment: а что именно блочить хотите: заблокировать ip или заблокировать по имени пользователя? Я так понимаю вам первое нужно. Тогда должно быть достаточно fail2ban

Answer (score 1):

Так вам фактически модуль авторизации нужен хороший, а не fail2ban...

Идея в том, что вы физически не сможете заблокировать удаленного пользователя в интернете. Как вы его пометите: кукой - сотрет / сменит браузер / зайдет из-под анонимной прокси, типа cameleo; запомните его ip - так под этим ip может весь район сидеть... 
Вы можете со своей стороны ограничить возможности тому человеку пытаться подбирать пароль для конкретного логина, например:
1) Хранить таблицу входов, где писать неудачные попытки login, timestamp;
2) При попытке входа проверять количество попыток неудачного входа для этого логина, если оно выше "нормального", то на совпадение авторизационных данных не проверять, а пользователю писать, типа: "Попробуйте через 30 минут".